# Creating a mesh on any object, duplicating the mesh and editing faces

Tags: mesh

[image]Id like to create an atomic model of a nanoparticle, a truncated octahedron to be precise. I know I can use the "set parent" function using small spheres to superimpose on an octahedron (itself created after bevelling a cube). Like I have shown in the picture.

I am facing a problem in making the new structure (truncated octahedron made of small spheres) independently editable. For example, id like to change its orientation wrt to the camera and also colour/texture different faces differently.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! As with most questions, an image that shows what you are trying to explain would be helpful. 

If I understand you correctly, you want objects to appear at the vertices of another object. This can be achieved with a dupli object. Let me know if that is what you want, I will write an answer, if so.

Comment: Hello Ben. Thank you for your prompt reply. I have updated my question with an image of what I managed to do since yesterday. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: Hello, Pranit! To apply different materials to the objects, the Make Duplicates Real function from the answer below will give you the necessary geometry to do so. You could already edit the position of the Dupli-Objects by editing their source object, but after using Make Duplicates real, they will be separate objects that you can manipulate independently.

Comment: Happy to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, assuming your problem is **getting actual geometry out of the Dupli-Objects** that you generate in the vertex-positions of your octahedron:

[image: Dupli Object Creation]

[image: Dupli Object to Actual Geometry]

- Create the object to be duplicated. In this example: the octahedron
- Create the object whose vertices indicate the positions of the Dupli-Objects. In this example: the cube
- Parent the octahedron to the cube
- Set the **Duplication Mode** in the Object Tab to **Verts**
- Select the object whose vertices position the clones (the cube)
- Create actual geometry from the clones by using the **Make Duplicates Real** function