# Assigning texture and colour to object groups

Tags: texturing, color, groups

[image]

Hello,

Id like to make groups for the different faces of this structure you can see above, and then assign different colours to the faces. Would appreciate any help on how to group them and colour them efficiently.

Thanks!

Pranit

Comment: I guess just use B to Boxselect from the Top (Numpad 7) and use Boxdeselect (I think it was holding while selecting or something like that) to cut your selection from other views (left, front) Use Wireframemode for that

Comment: Problem is that even after I annually select the spheres on a particular face  and change the color, the color of the entire structure changes. is there a way to apply it to only the current selection?

Comment: Look into "Linking Materials". This will allow you to make multiple objects share the same material, meaning, they will update all together when you make changes to one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi2tjN3iQNw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem seems to be linked Object Data. You need to make your Objects Local first and regroup them. First to make them local press <kbd>U</kbd> > "Object and Data", while all objects are selected. Then select your group that should always have the same color and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > "Object Data" to group them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your life a lot easier, by **going one step back**.

[image: Split Faces for Easier Grouping]

**Split the faces of your octahedron apart** by selecting the parts in Edit Mode and the hitting <kbd>P</kbd> and Separate by Selection.

Then you can **generate your spheres on top of the separate polygons** with the **Duplication Option** in the Object Tab from your last question. [Creating a mesh on any object, duplicating the mesh and editing faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134797/creating-a-mesh-on-any-object-duplicating-the-mesh-and-editing-faces/)

That way, you do not have to manually select from a huge number of intersecting objects.